# Travelling Europe by Train

Tags: trains, western-europe

I'm travelling to Western Europe in late September for 6 weeks and I'm going to be travelling by train to my destinations. I'll be visiting (the listed cities are in desired visiting order)

- Paris
- Brussels
- Amsterdam
- Berlin
- Vienna
- Venice
- Florence
- Rome
- Naples
- Barcelona
- Madrid
- Lisbon

I'm going to be spending an average of 2-3 days in each city (except Paris, I'll be spending 4-6 days there).

I've looked at rail passes for youth, and I don't know if the passes will be the best option for my travels? Should I buy the pass? Should I buy individual tickets when I arrive in Europe? Should I cut out some cities out?

TL;DR I'll need to purchase the 22 day pass in one month which comes to $938 CDN. Is it cheaper to buy individual tickets?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of train travel. This is an opinion based comment, but I think: You need to discard about a third those cities for a 6 week trip. Then make sure you're flexible, where you can leave if you don't like a place, or stay longer if you do. Or if you decide to go somewhere else. Eurail passes are based on travel days, so when you visit more cities you spend more money and time on travel, and have less time to enjoy each place.

Comment: It appears your question has been closed, but for an excellent guide to choosing between passes and individual tickets, take a look at [Seat61's guide to Eurail passes](https://www.seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm).

Comment: Why only train? Besides that your schedule is rather action packed, why not take a bus on some of these legs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the 22 day pass in one month [costs less](https://www.interrail.eu/de/interrailpaesse/global-pass) than 938$. About 750$ CDN if you take today's exchange rate (~x1.5). Also this is the rate for adults, but if you are younger (up to 27 years old) you'd pay even less (something like 500$).

EDIT: as pointed out by Pont's comment, in order to be able to travel with Interrail (different from Eurail or whatever) you have to be European citizen and one of the nations you would have to choose would be your homeland. Yet, even with a higher fare, it is still the best option.

Yes, the pass would be your best option. Even if you plan the whole trip a bunch of months in advance (most rail-companies do not allow to reserve places more than 6 months before the trip), consider that a **regional** ticket covering a one way journey from Salzburg to Munich (approx 150km) costs ~40$ CDN at least.

Since you'd have to cover a lot of km and don't have a lot of time, regional trains would not be the best option. Aside from Italy (high-speed trains are *really* cheap if you buy ticket in advance - *source: I'm Italian*) and maybe Spain, everywhere else is pretty much expensive (*source: I don't live in Italy anymore*), so the Interrail ticket really looks like the best choice.

BONUS (opinion based): As the comment from Greg points out, you really did overplan. Big cities like Rome, Paris and Berlin need at least 4 days / 3 nights to visit. In Barcelona it is worth to live the nightlife a bit (well, in Rome, Paris and Berlin too), so you may want to be flexible.

Comment: You've linked the price of the Interrail pass, which isn't available to non-European residents. The 22-days-in-a-month [Eurail pass](https://www.eurail.com/en/eurail-passes/global-pass) is €614 for under-27s, which does indeed work out to a little over 900 CAD.

Comment: Also, where are you getting your Salzburg-Munich prices? On bahn.de, I'm seeing high-speed RailJet tickets in mid-September for €19,90 (~30 CAD).

Comment: On closer inspection, there isn't actually a "22 days in a month" pass -- it's "22 days continuous". Ah well, the question's closed now anyway, and I think the Seat61 page I gave in a comment to the question should address most of OP's concerns. Incidentally, I agree with you that the pass would be the best option, even at the higher Eurail prices.

Comment: Oh, yeah I totally forgot you have to be European citizen to travel with Interrail, sorry! About the Salzburg-Munich I was talking about the regional train combined with the "early-bird-fee".